# Multipling Long into float number results wrong in some case

Tags: java, casting, floating-point

See this below simple code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Long value = 91000L;
    System.out.println(value * 0.1);
    System.out.println(value * 0.2);
    System.out.println(value * 0.3);
    System.out.println(value * 0.4);
    System.out.println(value * 0.5);
    System.out.println(value * 0.6);
    System.out.println(value * 0.7);
    System.out.println(value * 0.8);
    System.out.println(value * 0.9);
}
```

the result is this:

```
9100.0
18200.0
27300.0
36400.0
45500.0
54600.0
63699.99999999999 //incorrect!
72800.0
81900.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a correct result because working with double is not precise as working with integer types.

This is why in case you compare two `double` numbers, you have to do smth. like this:

```
public static boolean isEqual(double one, double two) {
    return one >= two - 1E6 && one <= two + 1E6;
}
```

P.S. [4.2.3. Floating-Point Types, Formats, and Values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3)

In case you want to print correct value, you have to use `BigDecimal`:

```
BigDecimal val = BigDecimal.valueOf(91000);
BigDecimal res = val.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.7));
System.out.println(res); // 63000.0
```

In some cases, you could increase precision:

```
long value = 91000L;
System.out.println(value * 0.7);    // 63699.99999999999
System.out.println((value * 7) / 10);   // 63700
```

Comment: could you explain why 63699.99999999999 is equal to 63700 in double?

Comment: It is a matter of rounding. The numbers 0.1, 0.2, ... do not have a precise representation when expressed a a sum a powers of two (only 0.5=2^-1 has).  When multiplied by anything the result will be imprecise. Then it is rounded. Depending on it this may lead to the expected result or not. In the same way as 3/3=1, while 3*(1/3)=3*0.333...333 will be different of 1 in decimal.

Comment: Please do not recommend that people compare floating-point numbers with a tolerance. [There is no general solution for comparing floating-point numbers for equality.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21261885/298225) Using a tolerance decreases false negatives (reports that numbers are not equal when the ideal results of real-number mathematics would be equal) at the expense of increasing false positives (reports that numbers are equal that are in fact not equal). That is okay in some applications but will break some applications. It should not be recommended for general use.

Comment: Also “working with double is not precise as working with integer types” is not a correct statement. At modest magnitudes, `double` is of course more **precise** than integer types because it has fraction bits, and integer does not. For example, `7/3` has a 14% error in integer arithmetic but the error in `double` arithmetic is tiny.