# Rounding off floating numbers in cpp

Tags: c++, io, floating-point

For a particular question, I need to perform calculations on a floating number, round it off to 2 digits after the decimal place, and assign it to a variable for comparison purposes. I tried to find a solution to this but all I keep finding is how to print those rounded numbers (using `printf` or `setprecision`) instead of assigning them to a variable.
Please help.

Comment: This is a C++ question, not a C question. Please remove the C tag.

Comment: It is not actually possible to round numbers exactly to two decimal places in a binary-based floating-point format, except those that are multiples of ¼ (those that end in .00, .25, .50, or .75). And attempting to round to make a comparison is generally a bad idea, as rounding makes errors larger near the rounding points, not smaller. [There is no general solution for comparing floating-point numbers that contain errors from previous operations.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21261885/298225) For a solution specific to your problem, you should explain the context of your problem.

Comment: By chance are you calculating something that represents a monetary amount?  If so, have you considered converting from dollars with a decimal point to absolute cents (as an integer).

Comment: @selbie Basing computations based on cents is not going to cut it. The smallest division of a dollar commonly in use (e.g. gasoline prices) is the mill, or 1/1000 of a dollar. Even using that as the basic unit may not be sufficient, as point out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/149050/780717), for example.

Comment: @njuffa: SEC rule 612 sets $0.0001 as the increment for prices of stocks under $1/share.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Another example I shall add to my list of random numerical factoids :-)

Answer (score 1):

> round it off to 2 digits after the decimal place, and assign it to a variable for comparison purposes

To avoid errors that creep in when using binary floating point in a decimal problem, consider alternatives.

Direct approach has corner errors due to [double rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Double_rounding) and overflow.   These errors may be tolerable for OP larger goals

```
// Errors: 
// 1) x*100.0, round(x*100.0)/100.0 inexact.
// Select `x` values near "dddd.dd5" form an inexact product `x*100.0`
// and may lead to a double rounding error and then incorrect result when comparing.
// 2) x*100.0 may overflow.
int compare_hundredth1(double x, double ref) {
  x = round(x*100.0)/100.0;
  return (x > ref) - (x < ref);
}
```

We can do better.

---

When a wider floating point type exist:

```
int compare_hundredth2(double x, double ref) {
  auto x_rounded = math::round(x*100.0L);
  auto ref_rounded = ref*100.0L;
  return (x_rounded > ref_rounded) - (x_rounded < ref_rounded);
}
```

To use the same width floating point type takes more work:

All finite large values of `x, ref` are whole numbers and need no rounding to the nearest 0.01.

```
int compare_hundredth3(double x, double ref) {
  double x_whole; 
  auto x_fraction = modf(x, &x_whole);
  // If rounding needed ...
  if (x_fraction != 0.0) {
    if (x - 0.01 > ref) return 1;  // x much more than ref
    if (x + 0.01 < ref) return -1; // x much less than ref
    // x, ref nearly the same
    double ref_whole; 
    auto ref_fraction = modf(x, &ref_whole);
    x -= ref_whole;
    auto x100 = (x - ref_whole)*100; // subtraction expected to be exact here.
    auto ref100 = ref_fraction*100;
    return (x100 > ref100) - (x100 < ref100);
  }
  return (x > ref) - (x < ref);
}
```

---

The above assume `ref` is without error.  If this is not so, consider using a *scaled* `ref`.

---

Note: The above sets aside not-a-number concerns.

---

More clean-up later.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do something like that:

```
#include <cmath> // 'std::floor'
#include <limits> // 'std::numeric_limits'
// Round value to granularity
template<typename T> inline T round(const T x, const T gran)
   {
    //static_assert(gran!=0);
    return gran * std::floor( x/gran + std::numeric_limits<T>::round_error() );
   }

double rounded_to_cent = round(1.23456, 0.01); // Gives something near 1.23
```

Be sure you know how floating point types work though.

---

Addendum: I know that this topic has already been extensively covered in other questions, but let me put this small paragraph here.
Given a real number, you can represent it with -almost- arbitrary accuracy with a (base10) literal like `1.2345`, that's a string that you can type with your keyboard.
When you store that value in a floating point type, let's say a `double`, you -almost- always loose accuracy because probably your number won't have an exact representation in the finite set of the numbers representable by that type.
Nowadays `double` uses 64 bits, so it has 2^64 symbols to represent the not numerable infinity of real numbers: that's a H2O molecule in an infinity of infinite oceans.
The representation error is relative to the value; for example in a IEEE 754 double, over 2^53 not all the integer values can be represented.
So when someone tells that the "result is wrong" they're technically right; the "acceptable" result is application dependent.

Comment: This produces incorrect results. For example, for `round(0.104999996721744537353515625f, .01f)`, it rounds up to 0.10999999940395355224609375 (when the IEEE-754 32-bit “single” format is used with correct rounding), whereas the correct result is to round down to near .10 (the nearest representable value is 0.100000001490116119384765625).

Comment: The use of `std::numeric_limits<T>::round_error()` is inappropriate. `round_error` describes the type of rounding that occurs in floating-point arithmetic. When round-to-nearest is in use, it is ½, to indicate the maximum rounding error is ½ ULP. When rounding modes such as toward-infinity or toward-zero are in use, it should be 1. While ½ is sort of suitable for the attempted (but incorrect) rounding intended here, the value of 1 would not make this work in other rounding modes.

Comment: The choice of `floor` is also odd, as this sort of rounding is usually preferred to be symmetric around zero. Instead of using `floor` and adding an incorrect symbolic constant, one could use a choice of `nearbyint` (to use the current rounding mode) or `round` (to round halfway cases away from zero).

Comment: The choice to express granularity directly instead of as its reciprocal makes it impossible to pass decimal granularities in a binary floating-point format. One-hundredth, .01, cannot be expressed exactly in a binary floating-point format. For example, passing `.01f` actually passes 0.00999999977648258209228515625. This will cause increasingly large errors with increasing inputs even if the code inside the routine used infinitely precise arithmetic.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Floating point types are indeed a very slippery topic! Please post a proper reply, that would help the community

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example with a custom function that rounds up the floating number `f` to `n` decimal places. Basically, it multiplies the floating number by 10 to the power of N to separate the decimal places, then uses `roundf` to round the decimal places up or down, and finally divides back the floating number by 10 to the power of N (N is the amount of decimal places). Works for C and C++:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float my_round(float f, unsigned int n)
{
    float p = powf(10.0f, (float)n);
    f *= p;
    f = roundf(f);
    f /= p;
    return f;
}

int main()
{
    float f = 0.78901f;
    printf("%f\n", f);

    f = my_round(f, 2); /* Round with 2 decimal places */
    printf("%f\n", f);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0.789010
0.790000
```

Comment: this is not working when comparing equal floats. It gives true for 0.790000<0.79

Comment: @sudorohit Please be careful about comparing float types, it's not so easy as it seems

Comment: This gets incorrect results. For example, it rounds 0.104999996721744537353515625 up to 0.10999999940395355224609375 (when the IEEE-754 32-bit “single” format is used with correct rounding), whereas the correct result is to round down to near .10 (the nearest representable value is 0.100000001490116119384765625).

Comment: @rdbo: The numbers I showed do not have too many decimal places to be printed, as proven by the fact that I printed them, using a C++ implementation. Any C++ implementation that uses the IEEE-754 32-bit binary format (or better) and correct rounding will print them. `printf` does not fail. You have to request more than the default number of digits displayed to see them all. The values represented are exactly the value I showed. 0.104999996721744537353515625, is exactly 14,092,861 / 2^27, which is why it is representable in `float`, and 0.100000001490116119384765625 is 13,421,773 / 2^27.