# Float epsilon is different in c++ than c#

Tags: c#, c++, floating-point, epsilon

So small question, I've been looking into moving part of my C# code to C++ for performance reasons.
Now when I look at my float.Epsilon in C# its value is different from my C++ value.

In C# the value, as described [by microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single.epsilon?view=net-5.0) is 1.401298E-45.

In C++ the value, as described [by cppreferences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits) is 1.19209e-07;

How can it be that the smallest possible value for a float/single can be different between these languages?

If I'm correct, the binary values should be equal in terms of number of bytes an maybe even their binary values. Or am I looking at this the wrong way?

Hope someone can help me, thanks!

Comment: The definitions of epsilon are different. In C# ist is the difference between 0 and the next value an in C++ it is the difference between 1 and the next value.

Comment: That Microsoft page is rife with bad statements about floating-point. Avoid using the information in it. Some problems: (a) “zero and half the value of Epsilon are considered to be equal”: You cannot have half the value of Epsilon in a `Float`; it is not representable. (b) “format consists of a sign, a 23-bit mantissa or significand…”: The significand is 24 bits, although stored as 23 bits in one field and 1 bit depending on the exponent field.

Comment: (c) “machine epsilon, which represents the upper bound of the relative error due to rounding…”: It can be a gauge of the error in a single operation, not quite right to say it represents the upper bound or that it is for the relative error. With round-to-nearest, the actual upper bound is ½ an ULP, and the true relative error is a bit complicated, as it varies across a binade.

Comment: (d) “the constant on the right side is precise only to the specified digits”: Both values have the same precision; the one on the right is inaccurate for ⅓. Microsoft’s statements about precision are [bad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61614323/298225).

Comment: (e) “If you create a custom algorithm that determines whether two floating-point numbers can be considered equal, you must use a value that is greater than the Epsilon constant to establish the acceptable absolute margin of difference for the two values to be considered equal.”: [There is no general solution for comparing floating-point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21261885/298225); every application must deal with both false positives and false negatives, which may be particular to its situation. So it is not true that “you must use a value that is greater than the Epsilon constant.”

Comment: (f) “On ARM systems, the value of the Epsilon constant is too small to be detected, so it equates to zero.”: I suspect they are trying to say the flush-to-zero behavior for denormals interferes with using the Epislon constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second value you quoted is the [machine epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) for IEEE `binary32` values.

The first value you quoted is *NOT* the machine epsilon. From the documentation you linked:

> The value of the Epsilon property is not equivalent to machine epsilon, which represents the upper bound of the relative error due to rounding in floating-point arithmetic.

From the [wiki Variant Definitions section for machine epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon#Variant_definitions):

> The IEEE standard does not define the terms machine epsilon and unit roundoff, so differing definitions of these terms are in use, which can cause some confusion.

...

> The following different definition is much more widespread outside academia: Machine epsilon is defined as the difference between 1 and the next larger floating point number.

The C# documentation is using that variant definition.

So the answer is that you are comparing two different types of Epsilon.

Comment: Also note that you can use `std::numeric_limits<float>::denorm_min()` in C++ to get C#'s `float.Epsilon`.

Answer (score 2):

#### C++

> Returns the machine epsilon, that is, the difference between 1.0 and the next value representable by the floating-point type T.
> https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon

#### C#

> Represents the smallest positive Single value that is greater than zero. This field is constant.
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single.epsilon?view=net-5.0

#### Conclusion

C# has next value from 0, C++ has next from 1. Two completely different things.

Edit: The other answer is probably more correct

Answer (score 0):

From the link you referenced, you should use the value FLT_TRUE_MIN ("minimum positive value of float") if you want something similar to .NET Single.Epsilon ("smallest positive single value that is greater than zero").