# How to compare floating point numbers in Perl for "equality"

Tags: perl, floating-point

Note that I had set "equality" in double-quotes, so read on about the details:

I wrote some code that stores Perl objects in a file and retrieves them from there.
I'm using my own JSON-based code using text representation to be independent from Perl.
When I wrote a self-test checking whether the loaded object is the same as the stored object, I got a surprise:

```perl-db
  DB<14> x $self->time() == $other->time()
0  ''
  DB<15> x $self->time()
0  4842276.32536854
  DB<16> x  $other->time()
0  4842276.32536854
  DB<17> x $self->time() == $other->time()
0  ''
  DB<18> x $self->time() - $other->time()
0  '-2.79396772384644e-09'
```

So while the numbers output look identical, their internal representation is not.
However when I create a JSON representation for both, there is no difference (different numbers this time (as time went on); also note that the order of the fields varies as it's a Perl HASH):

```perl-db
  DB<1> x $self->flat
0  '{"time":4842854.29538268,"crc":23407,"use_counter":19}'
  DB<2> x $other->flat
0  '{"use_counter":19,"crc":23407,"time":4842854.29538268}'
```

(The real objects are more complex, but this shows the principle; the time value comes from `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC) # useTime::HiRes qw(clock_gettime CLOCK_MONOTONIC)`)

Now I wonder:
Should I simply try to compare the numbers as strings (as a work-around), or should I use an elaborate ("correct") solution like https://stackoverflow.com/a/33024979/6607497?

Comment: To see the full number, use `printf "%.1000g\n", $self->time();` instead.

Comment: Your link points to a python question. That would indeed be elaborate to perform in Perl.

Comment: @Bork, wut. The top answer uses `abs` (builtin) and `max` (List::Util, core, and could be replaced with `?:`). And the second uses `abs`. It would trivial to port, and using `?:` might actually make the first answer shorter in Perl! (Python's equivalent to `?:` is wordy.)

Comment: Oh, I see. I was assuming it was a mistake. I didn't read the code.

Comment: You wrote “So while the numbers output look identical, their internal representation is not.” Do you think the fact the numbers output look identical mean the represented numbers actually are identical, and the fact the internal representations are not identical means there are two different representations for the same number?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Considering different solutions for the original problem (float number is not equal after saving and restoring it via JSON (and using default string conversion)), I wanted to fix JSON save and restore instead of the floating point comparison.

So after temporarily using string comparison for the floating-point numbers (that would also fix the problem), I switched back to numeric comparison.
To make that work, I decided to save the numbers as hexadecimal [double representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64) (Perl's floats are always double internally).

The code basically became:

```perl
if ($encode) {
    return unpack('H*', pack('d>', $val));
} else {
    return unpack('d>', pack('H*', $val));
}
```

So `5274540.53703853` is saved as `41541eeb225ed6db`, for example.
I cross-checked with C, and it uses the same representation.

Answer (score 3):

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Typically you don't compare floating point numbers for equality because they can't exactly represent all (most?) values. There's always a little wiggle room in the low digits as the value tries to be as close to the value you want within the precision of the hardware. You might even have a lot of extra digits that are meaningless since the accuracy has already drifted.

Instead, you might compare them to see if they are close enough within some threshold (sometimes called "epsilon"):

```
if( abs($self->time - $other->time) < $epsilon ) { ... }
```

There are other ways that people try to handle this. One way is to make everything an integer so you don't have fractional values. That works until you run up against the maximum value of an integer. That makes things a bit easier for your serializer.

You can also use more heavyweight libraries such as [Math::BigRat](https://perldoc.perl.org/Math::BigRat), but then you still have to serialize and deserialize it correctly.

[Mark Jason Dominus's article on Moonpig](https://blog.plover.com/prog/Moonpig.html), a billing system that moved from floating point representing real currency to something else with a virtual currency is an interesting read.

Answer (score 1):

Your post does not show any reason some alternate comparison for equality needs to be used. Rather, it shows the conversion to JSON is not producing enough digits to distinguish numbers that are different. The solution for that is to produce more digits when converting to JSON. Producing 17 significant decimal digits suffices to distinguish numbers in the IEEE-754 binary64 format (also called “double precision”).

Your example code shows comparison of times. In this case, the different times are actually different times, and so a comparison for equality should report them as different. Reasons for accepting different numbers as equal arise when computations have been performed with rounding errors, so that two computed results are different but would have been equal if computed with exact real-number arithmetic. However, [there is no general solution for comparing floating-point numbers that contain errors from previous operations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21261885/298225). All methods to test for “approximate equality” introduce a possibility of incorrectly accepting as equal numbers that would not be equal if computed with exact real-number arithmetic. The amount of error that can be accepted (because the application and its users can tolerate it) and the amount of error that must be accepted (because rounding errors could have accumulated to that amount) are specific to the application and its uses and to the specific data involved.

Comment: You seems to have mis-interpreted my two *different* examples (as such, the numbers are different, as they are times), but the objects of interest are `self` vs. `other` (I thought that to be obvious): When outputting both values in the debugger, the output is identical, but still there is a difference in the actual numbers (see first example). The second example just gives (another!) example how the JSON might look like. Again you see two identical number representations there (even if the underlying numbers are actually different). Of course one solution is adding ,ore digits.

Comment: @U.Windl: Neither example shows a reason to treat two different numbers as equal. In one example, `$self-time()` and `$other->time()` are different numbers (because, apparently, they were reported by `clock_gettime` at actually different times) that a debugger shows the same way (because the debugger does not use enough digits). In the other, the same two parts of `$self` and `$other` are shown the same way (because JSON does not use enough digits). The numbers involved apparently represent actual different times, and no reason is stated to treat this as the same time, other than appearance…

Comment: … But it is the appearances that are wrong, not the numbers. No correction to the numerical comparison is needed; `$self->time() == $other->time()` is producing a correct result. The debugger and the JSON conversion are producing insufficient results that do not accurately represent the numbers, so they are the things that ought to be corrected.